# my jQuery hover code is repeating on hovers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now I have a problem and I don't know how I can solve it.

The problem is that if I hover the `.div` multiple times the animation just doesn't stop, but keeps going.

What I want is that the `.hidden` doesn't continue to `fadeIn` or `fadeOut`, if you hover it once or ten times it will only `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` once and not as many times as you've actually hovered the `.div`.

My current code is:

```
<div class="container-of-some-sort">

  <div class="div">
    <p class="nothidden">title</p>
    <p class="hidden">hey would you show me</p>
  </div>

  <div class="div">
    <p class="nothidden">title</p>
    <p class="hidden">hey would you show me</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

and JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
   $('.div').hover(function() {
   $(this).find(".hidden").fadeIn(1000);
   }, function() { 
   $(this).find(".hidden").fadeOut(500);
   });
});
```

How can I do this?

**I've made an [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y8ynts48/) to display my problem.**

Comment: Your best option here is to use the css :hover selector. Apply transition property on the div. Then set its opacity to 0 by default and opacity to 1 when you hover it.

Comment: Yeah you're definately right @Tibs, I overthinked it.

Comment: that is not right my friend @Tibs

Comment: I really want to provide a code but I'm not infront of my computer right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`.stop(clearQueue,jumpToEnd)`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) with the `params` `clearQueue` and `jumpToEnd` as `true`.

as the `clearQueue` will **remove queued animation as well** and

`jumpToEnd` **to complete the current animation immediately**

By Default they are set to `true` .

```js
$(function() {
  $('.div').hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".hidden").stop(true, true).fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find(".hidden").stop(true, true).fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

```css
p.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.div {
  display: block;
  background: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-of-some-sort">

  <div class="div">
    <p class="nothidden">title</p>
    <p class="hidden">hey would you show me</p>
  </div>

  <div class="div">
    <p class="nothidden">title</p>
    <p class="hidden">hey would you show me</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Damn, it was that simple... I didn't know about `stop` until now, thank you for the explanation. Highly appreciated =)

Comment: No problem glad i was of some help for you :) thank you friend